# why do i have to render the jquery with the view

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, asp.net-mvc-4

Im having some issues with query and binding as it seems.

in my _Layout i got the jquery at the bottom of the page, it got a `.on('click')`

In got a partialView that got a "add item" link, when i click it makes a `$.post()` that returns a parialview and populates it in a div container.

Next time when i try to add another item with a click on the same link, it just acts like a link and refreshed the site, like it lost the binding to the jquery. If i choose to have the jquery in the partial that renders over it work every time, but for the sake of structure i dont want to have jquery scripts in the middle of the page.

Why is that and what can i do?

**EDIT:**
this is the bind i got. it works like before just once.

```
$('.menu-day').on('click', 'a.addItem', function (e) {
          e.preventDefault();
          console.log('ok');
          addRow($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

Comment: jQuery should always be in the master page.

Comment: yea thats what i mean. `for the sake of structure i dont want to have jquery scripts in the middle of the page.`

Comment: example code maybe even a jsfiddle of it breaking/not working

Comment: @Mutmatt its hard to do a jsfiddle its so much more involved with a post to a controller. My question kinda becomes why does the link lose it binding to the jquery? i think `.live()` would have solved this but im not into using that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using $().on('click', function() { ... }) works a lot like a traditional .click() binding in that the element has to exist on the page *before* you bind it. For example:

```
$("ul li").on('click', function() { ... })
```

So that isn't going to work with dynamically added list elements. What you can do is specify a selector inside the click which will listen for events that bubble up to the context. For example:

```
$("ul").on('click', 'li', function() { ... });
```

Now clicks on list items will trigger regardless of when they were added, since it's the container list that was bound and is simply listening for a specific eventTarget.

Comment: ya, he hasn't posted his click handler, but i suspect he's not using the on method right.  In regards to some of the other comments, .live() was deprecated and replaced by .on()

Comment: thats interesting, can i add a specific selector with a class into that like `$(".click-me").on('click', 'a.click-me', function() { ... });?` or is it just enough with `$("a.click-me").on('click', 'a', function() { ... });?`

Comment: @JohnB im using the `.on()` like Mikes first example

Comment: @Dejan.S I'm guessing you're doing a full replace of html inside your container, including the original link. When you do that, you nuke the event binding (and create your problem). So you need to make your initial selector the container, and then use the specific selector to bind the add functionality.

Comment: @MikeRobinson yea thats about right. but i don't get how you mean with selector the container, I will update my question.

Comment: @Dejan.S maybe try using a broader container selector, like $(document.body).on(..... unless you need to be really specific

Answer (score 0):

You can use delegate() method which binds the event which are present in Dom and elements added in the future. Go through this [link](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/)

Comment: You can, however this is deprecated in 1.8